# post ajax only works by using backslash at end

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post, backslash

I have a json endpoint at my wordpress. I need to send parameter by url and also with post.

This works: `http://<mydomain>/wordpress/?my_action=getBooks`

This not: `http://<mydomain>/wordpress?my_action=getBooks`

If i send without backslash the post parameter is missing on server side.
Why i need this this backslash?

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://<mydomain>/wordpress/?my_action=getBooks',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {test: 'abc' },
        }).done(function (data) {
            <do something>
        }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a forward slash, not a backslash. The backslash leans backwards (\) and the forward slash leans forward (/).

Wordpress rewrites by default use the trailing slash. I think a tweak to your .htaccess (assuming you're using apache) should remove this.

I haven't tested this but may work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```